# Renaming Checkbox Fields with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

im am trying to rename fields in itext. I can successfully rename textfields, but i am getting errors renaming checkboxfields. Here is the code so far:

```
try {
    pdfReader = new PdfReader(s_pdfread);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Can't create Filestream from " + s_pdfread);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    ShowHelp();
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}

List <renameJob> jobsToDo = new List<renameJob> ();

try {
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(s_pdfwrite, FileMode.Create)) {
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fs);
        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

        foreach (var field in stamper.AcroFields.Fields) {
            Console.WriteLine("fieldKeySRC: " + field.Key);
            string newFieldname = field.Key.Replace(s_searchFor, s_replaceWith);
            newFieldname = newFieldname.Replace(".", "");

            // special name for checkbox
            /*switch (stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldType(field.Key)) {
                case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    newFieldname = newFieldname + ".0";
                    break;
            } planned for future. In finaly version i need to add this .0 */

            if (field.Key != newFieldname) {
                renameJob job = new renameJob();
                job.oldName = field.Key;
                job.newName = newFieldname;
                jobsToDo.Add(job);
            }
        }

        foreach (renameJob job in jobsToDo) {
            if (fields.RenameField(job.oldName, job.newName) == true) {
                Console.WriteLine("renameField: " + job.oldName + " to " + job.newName);
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("!!! failed: renameField: " + job.oldName + " to " + job.newName);
            }

        }

        stamper.Close();
```

why does this fail for checkboxes and work fine for textboxes.... ?

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? One remark to start with, though: The period character has a special meaning in PDF: It is used as a separator for the partial names in a fully qualified name corresponding to the fields in a field hierarchy. Adding ".0" to a field name, therefore, implicitly means that another level in the hierarchy would have to be added, and I doubt that that's done under the hood here.

Comment: fields.RenameField returns false. Even if i do not add ".0" to checkboxes this function fails. If i rename a textbox from "mybox" to "hisbox" everything goes fine. if i do the same to a checkbox the functions fails with false ....

Comment: Please supply a PDF for which your sample source fails.

Answer (score 1):

As mkl explains, the "." in a field name is NOT part of the name, it's there to indicate a hierarchy.

Suppose you have a parent field named "parent" with two kids "kid1" and "kid2". In this case, the fully qualified names of the kid fields are "parent.kid1" and "parent.kid2".

With iText, you can rename fields, but you can't change the hierarchy. For instance: you can change the fully qualified name "mybox" into "hisbox", you can change the fully qualified name "parent.kid1" into "parent.child1" and "parent.kid2" into "parent.child2".

**IT DOESN'T MATTER** if these fields are text fields, checkbox fields, or any other type of field!

In other words: your question is wrong! The problem you have, is that you're not trying to rename a field. Instead you're trying to change "parent.kid1" into "parentkid1" and "parent.kid2" into "parentkid2". That's not the same as renaming! That's removing the hierarchy, changing a parent and two kids into two parentless kids! You can't use the rename function to do this.

If you really want to throw away the hierarchy, you need to add two new fields "parentkid1" and "parentkid2" that copy the properties of "parent.kid1" and "parent.kid2". Once you have these copies, you need to remove "parent", "kid1" and "kid2".

That's much more work. I'd advise against it, as it's an error-prone operation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. But as i mentioned: The problem is still there, even if i rename a checkbox form "old" to "new". So what is the problem in this simple case ?

Comment: These dots are my problem i the source file. I got a delivery where i tried to rename all checkboxes. But the checkbox is named something with "." while i try to name ist "check1". This fails too :-(

Comment: If the '.' is part of the name, then your PDF isn't compliant to ISO-32000-1. Show us the PDF!